# Ant target to move directories out of another directory

Tags: java, ant, task

How to move directories to one directory using an Ant task?

My directory structure is like:

```
my/directory/root
               |-dir1/one/same/lib
               |-dir2/two/same/lib
               |-dir3/three/same/lib
               |-dir4/four/same/lib
```

And I would like to move and scale folders "same/lib" and move it to "my/directory/root"
(finally:  my/directory/root/same/lib)

Comment: what do you mean by 'scale' - merge the contents of those 4 directories to one?

Comment: Yes. I mean merge those 4 directories to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<target name="moveDirs">
  <mkdir dir="my/directory/root/merged" failonerror="false">
  <move todir="my/directory/root/merged">
    <fileset dir="my/directory/root">
      <include name="dir*/*"/>
    </fileset>
    <mapper>
        <regexpmapper from="^(.*?)dir[0-9]+.(.*)$" to="\1\2"/>
    </mapper>
  </move>
</target>
```

**Reference:**

- [`<move>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html)
- [Mapper type](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html)

Comment: It doesn't work. I get log: [move] Skipping self-move of my/directory/root/dir1/same

Comment: Or do you know how to do it with define in property file this folders?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work too :(. 
I get: An Ant BuildException has occured: Could not create type regexpmapper due to No supported regular expression matcher found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpMatcher

Comment: you will need an additional lib in your classpath. info here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Ant Move Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html). 
Try the following:

```
<target name="moveDirs">
  <mkdir dir="my/directory/root/same/lib" failonerror="false">
  <move todir="my/directory/root/same/lib">
    <fileset dir="my/directory/root/dir1/one/same/lib">
      <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
  </move>
  <move todir="my/directory/root/same/lib">
    <fileset dir="my/directory/root/dir2/two/same/lib">
      <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
  </move>
  <move todir="my/directory/root/same/lib">
    <fileset dir="my/directory/root/dir3/three/same/lib">
      <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
  </move>
  <move todir="my/directory/root/same/lib">
    <fileset dir="my/directory/root/dir4/four/same/lib">
      <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
  </move>
</target>
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it more automaticaly? Because directories like 'dir1' 'dir2' is too much.